# Express the number 2024 by the sum, difference, and product of other numbers

Tags: output-formatting

I know that (I found it on Facebook, https://www.facebook.com/search/top?q=tran%20nam%20dung) $2^3 + 3^3 + 4^3 + 5^3 + 6^3 + 7^3 + 8^3 + 9^3 = 2024$
and
$1234 - 5 + 6 + 789 = 2024$.

$1 + 2 * 3 * 456 + 7 - 8 *90 = 2024$.

What is another expression?

Comment: `I know that ...`: May I know how you know?

Comment: @Syed I see it on Facebook.

Comment: Diff of two squares  (45+1) * (45-1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Happy new year to all!

The prime factorisation of the number is:

```
2^3 11 23
```

which we can get from

```
FactorInteger[2024]
```

Also, 2024 is a [`Harshad number`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harshad_number#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20harshad%20number,or%20n%2DNiven)

Implementation from [`OEIS`](https://oeis.org/A005349)

```
harshadQ[n_] := Mod[n, Plus @@ IntegerDigits@n] == 0;
Select[Range[2024], harshadQ]
```

It is, also, a [`Tetrahedral_number`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_number)

Implementation from [`OEIS`](https://oeis.org/A000292)

```
Accumulate[Accumulate[Range[0, 22]]]
```

It is, also, a [`Pernicious number`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pernicious_number#:%7E:text=In%20number%20theory%2C%20a%20pernicious,written%20as%20a%20binary%20number.)

Implementation from [`OEIS`](https://oeis.org/A052294)

```
Select[Range[2025], PrimeQ[DigitCount[#, 2][[1]]] &] // Last
```

It can be written as a palindrome minus its digits reversed

```
6226 - 4202
```

And, also

```
77 + Sum[index, {index, 78, 99}]
```

Answer (score 8):

```
opers = {"+", "-", "*"};
Monitor[
     Reap[
      Do[
       Do[
        ts = ToString /@ FromDigits /@ TakeList[Range@9, pd];
        Do[
          exp = StringJoin[Riffle[ts, po]];
           If[ToExpression@exp == 2024, Sow[exp]]
         , {po, Tuples[opers, Length@ip - 1]}]
        , {pd, Permutations@ip}]
       , {ip, IntegerPartitions[9]}]
      ]
     , ip][[2,1]]

{"1234-5+6+789", "12*34*5-6+7-8-9"}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is also dodecahedral, `n*(3*n - 1)*(3*n - 2)/2`, `n = 8`.